# Foreach loop not always displaying

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm retrieving data out of a database using PHP's PDO extension. I never had a problem with this and it always shows up in all browsers. BUT when I tested the website on a friends laptop, the foreach loop works but  the content is not displayed. The content is present in the source code.

this is how I set up the code that should be displayed:

```
<?php
  foreach($advertentiesManager->recenteAdvertenties() as $advertentie) {
    $verkoperData = $usersManager->userData($advertentie->verkoper);
?>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin:10px 0;">
          <div class="advertentie">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="img" style="background:url('images/categorie/<?php echo $advertentie->categorie; ?>.jpg') no-repeat center center;background-size:cover;"></div>
            <a href="profiel/<?php echo $advertentie->verkoper; ?>"><div class="picture" style="background:url('<?php echo str_replace("../", "", $verkoperData->foto); ?>') no-repeat center center;background-size:cover;"></div></a>
            <div class="prijs"><p class="h2">&#0128; <?php echo $advertentie->verkoopprijs; ?></p></div>
            <div style="padding: 10px;padding-left:80px;margin-top:-40px;">
              <a href="<?php echo $advertentie->type.'/'.strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $advertentie->titel)).'-'.$advertentie->id; ?>">
                <?php echo $advertentie->titel; ?>
              </a>
              <br>
              <p style="color:#777;font-size:.9em;">
<?php
  $beschrijving = strip_tags($advertentie->omschrijving);
  $max_length = 100;
  if (strlen($beschrijving) > $max_length) {
    $offset = ($max_length - 3) - strlen($beschrijving);
    $beschrijving = substr($beschrijving, 0, strrpos($beschrijving, ' ', $offset)) . '... <a href="'.$advertentie->type.'/'.strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $advertentie->titel.'-'.$advertentie->id)).'">Meer</a>';
  } else {
    $beschrijving = $advertentie->omschrijving;
  }
  echo $beschrijving;              
?>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
<?php
  }      
?>
```

You can view a live example at http://www.coupontrade.nl/ the content should be displayed under "Recente advertenties" and above the twitter part.

Comment: I do not know the answer, but your searchbox is vulnerable to XSS scripting (you can easily see it if you search <script>alert(1)</script> at your searchbox). It is highly recommended to close this security hole :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I never had a problem with that... I do agree that i shouldnt be doing that when unnecessarily tho. But do you see the content when viewing the website?

Comment: I see 3 visible `<div class="col-md-4" style="margin:10px 0;">...</div>` blocks. I don't see your issue.

Comment: man you surely need to work on your methodology, its looks quite heavy  mixture of code css/html/php. Keep things where they belong first.

Comment: @sean that's the problem, some people see it, some dont...

Comment: @pronox already made adjustments and put everything where it belongs. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Can you narrow down browser/os of those who don't see it? If it is in the page html source code it could be a browser css (javascript?) compatibility issue.

Comment: @user3316397 when i only see three `<br>` tags and your link`<a href="alles" class="h4">Bekijk alle advertenties</a>`, nothing else in the source code

Comment: @sean Yes, for two friends it's Chrome and Firefox that don't display the content while another friend doesn't have a problem in one of thos browsers. IE seems to display it without a problem.

Comment: @pronox hmm in what browser are you viewing the page? This is the first time it doesn't show up in the source either

Comment: If you split the technologies out using an established design methodology, you will also find each component of your website a lot easier to test.

Comment: @user3316397 sorry was looking at wrong section, i got your all 3 advertentie, don't know what that is but looks fine no issue here

Comment: Okay thanks. Could it possibly be a problem with buffering? Or cookies...

Comment: Let's name some other web technologies that may or may not be responsible.